# Understanding an estimate of the Probability of Intersections of Possibly Dependent Events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I am trying to understand the following estimate:

Let $X, Y, Z$ be random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ and $T_1, T_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $X$ and $Z$ are independent and  $Y := f(X, Z)$ for some function $f$. It is claimed that
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ X \in T_1, Y \in T_2 \} \leq \mathbb{P}\{ X \in T_1 \} \sup_{x \in T_1} \mathbb{P}\{ f(x, Z) \in T_2 \}.
$$
This estimate seems very elementary, but I am having trouble to see why this is true. Any advices on how to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $T_1$ and$T_2$ are Borel sets we have $$P[X\in T_1, f(X,Z) \in T_2]=\int 1_{x\in T_1 f(x,z) \in T_2}dF_{X,Z}(x,z)$$$$=\int_{T_1} P[f(x,Z) \in T_2]dF_{X}(x)$$ $$\le \sup_{x \in T_1} P[f(x,Z)\in T_2] P(X\in T_1].$$  where we have used Fubini's Theorem in second line.